# I want a small circle in search bar icon is it possible

Tags: flutter, design-patterns, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want code which contains border in the search bar
[image: as shown]

The code is as follow

child: Row(
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.menu,
                                color: Colors.black,

```
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print("your menu action here");
                          _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                        },

                        ),
                        Expanded(


                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(

                            hintText: "Search",


                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                        IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(

                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print("your menu action here");
                        },
                      ),

                      ]
                    ),
```

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Can you provide me with code..?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            print("your menu action here");
            _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
          },
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              cursorColor: Colors.black,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  gapPadding: 0.0,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    width: 1.0,
                  ),
                ),
                hintText: 'Search',
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  gapPadding: 0.0,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    width: 1.0,
                  ),
                ),
                suffixIcon: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black38,
                          offset: Offset(-5.0, 0.0),
                          blurRadius: 10,
                        )
                      ]),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  /* child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    mini: true,
                    elevation: 5.0,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                    ),
                  ),*/
                ),
                filled: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 15.0,
                  top: 0.0,
                  bottom: 0.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```